# where to run heroku ps:scale web=1?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, heroku

where to run the command heroku ps:scale web=1

heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/"

on this error.,

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean where to run the command? You can use heroku CLI or if you're on Windows, use Powershell. In Powershell, type , commit your files then push it into master before you use the command heroku ps:scale web=1